# Как заменить размеченный текст в WordprocessingDocument OpenXML?

Tags: c#, docx, openxml

Есть текст в документе *docx*, представленный в XML вот так:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="004C461E" w:rsidRDefault="0090423A">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="a4"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="0090423A">
    <w:t>[[</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
  <w:r w:rsidR="005D17CC" w:rsidRPr="005D17CC">
    <w:t>Договор.Клиент.ЮрНазвание</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="0090423A">
    <w:t>]]</w:t>
  </w:r>
 </w:p>
```

Требуется заменить, допустим `[[Договор.Клиент.ЮрНазвание]]`, имеется код:

```
var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true);
string text;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(document.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
{
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

text = text.Replace("[[Договор.Клиент.ЮрНазвание]]", "ООО «Рога и копыта»");

using (var sw = new StreamWriter(document.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
{
    sw.Write(text);
}
```

Разумеется просто замена не получится, между `[[` и текстом внутри есть некоторая разметка. Если заменять регулярными выражениями то неясно какая комбинация тегов может оказаться рядом внутри искомого текста.

Как реализовать замену, подобную той, что выполняется в самом Word, по отображаемому тексту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готового, тривиального решения с рамках библиотеки `OpenXML` найти не удалось.

Найдено решение, [описанное в этой статье](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/05/12/search-and-replace-text-in-an-open-xml-wordprocessingml-document.aspx), которое пробегает по всем узлам и и выполняет замену, даже если части одного заменяемого выражения находятся в разных узлах.

Использование сводится к вызову:

```
var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true);
SearchAndReplacer.SearchAndReplace(document, ("[[Договор.Клиент.ЮрНазвание]]", "ООО «Рога и копыта»", true);
```

[Сам код решения](http://openxmldeveloper.org/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-00-14-83-57/SearchAndReplace.zip) слишком объемный, что бы вынести его сюда.