# Библиотека для работы с .rtf или .docx файлами через WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, библиотеки

Пишу приложение на WPF (язык С#), которое будет формировать и заполнять шаблоны документов (письма, договоры  и т.п.).
Его задача - взять данные из WPF формы, создать новый файл по шаблону и вставить в созданный файл данные из формы.
Никакого форматирования не предполагается. Только - жирный шрифт местами и табличка на 2 ячейки.
Для универсальности, хочу использовать rtf формат файла, чтобы программа могла работать с Open/Libre Office. Если не получится, то буду использовать .docx

Вопрос: есть ли какие-нибудь бесплатные (сама программа некоммерческая, но может использоваться в работе) библиотеки кроме Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, которые могут выполнить такую задачу?

Comment: OpenXml, но вам не понравится с ним работать

Comment: Ну и язык на котором пишите укажите

Comment: С#. Не подумал сразу.

Comment: Как вариант - сделать шаблонный docx, в котором в нужных местах придумать какие-нибудь местозаполнители, затем просто делать поиск и замену этих местозаполнителей на свой текст. Когда-то приходилось делать такое, получилось несколько костыльно, но, на удивление, довольно стабильно. Помог этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471793/218063 просто так искать и менять в docx не выйдет, так как там даже идущие подряд буквы могут оказаться в разных тегах xml

Comment: Как успехи? Если все получается, давайте закроем вопрос как дубликат к вышеуказанному. Если нет - опишите проблемы.

Comment: Да, давайте закроем. Это мне надо удалить?

Comment: Я помечу как дубликат, а вы подтвердите.